# Spring GraphQLmultiple schemas with Query per file

Tags: spring, graphql, spring-graphql

with Spring-GraphQl if I have following two schemas in the resources/graphql folder:

schema1:

```
type Query {
  bookById(id: ID): Book
}

type Book {
  id: ID
  name: String
  pageCount: Int
  author: Author
}

type Author {
  id: ID
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}
```

schema2:

```
type Query {
  personByName(name: String): Person
}

type Person {
  id: ID
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}
```

Spring-GraphQL seems to be merging them into one GraphQL schema file and starting of Spring-Boot Graphql app ends with following error:

Caused by: graphql.schema.idl.errors.SchemaProblem: errors=['Query' type [@1:1] tried to redefine existing 'Query' type [@1:1]]

When I change it to:

schema1:

```
type Query {
  bookById(id: ID): Book
  personByName(name: String): Person
}
```

schema2:

```
type Book {
  id: ID
  name: String
  pageCount: Int
  author: Author
}

type Author {
  id: ID
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}

type Person {
  id: ID
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}
```

it works perfectly good and I am able to call both queries with graphiql. How graphql spring works with multiple schemas? It seems spring-graphql merges files into one schema so multiple Query types per file breaks the app.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Thomas, were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, yes I followed advice from Brian Clozel and it worked. I marked his answer as helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Spring GraphQL is loading all schema resources under the configured location and is using [`TypeDefinitionRegistry::merge`](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/fec817518772e0bcc1cdce1ee10193fe659973fd/src/main/java/graphql/schema/idl/TypeDefinitionRegistry.java#L52) to create a single schema out of them.

I think that redifining any type (even the `Query` one) should raise an error, otherwise this could hide important issues and conflicting schema definitions. That's what GraphQL Java's `TypeDefinitionRegistry` is doing.

You can organize your schema files like this:

`graphql/schema.graphqls`

```
type Query {

}

// add common directives, scalars, etc
```

`graphql/books.graphqls`

```
extend type Query {
  bookById(id: ID): Book
}

type Book {
  id: ID
  name: String
  pageCount: Int
  author: Author
}

type Author {
  id: ID
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}
```

`graphql/person.graphqls`

```
extend type Query {
  personByName(name: String): Person
}

type Person {
  id: ID
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}
```