# How to split GraphQL schema on the server side (spring boot application)

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I want to logically separate all my Graphql schemas into diff. entities. I am doing this in a spring-boot project.

I do not want to use Appolo or any other 3rd party libraries.

E.g.
book.graphql
author.graphql

I tried the solution provided, and I got no compile error but I am also not getting results from the query anymore.

[Spring GraphQLmultiple schemas with Query per file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965390/spring-graphqlmultiple-schemas-with-query-per-file/)

Please see below:

[image]

[image]

Can someone pls point me out if I am doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965390/spring-graphqlmultiple-schemas-with-query-per-file/) works as is.

The reason I was getting errors was that I had not implemented the endpoint.